# Onfocus: How to stop it prompting IE security box?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this on an html:

```
   <input type="text" name="username" size="10" alt="Username" value="Username"
    onfocus="if(this.value=='Username') this.value='';" />
```

But this prompts an irritating IE security box on browser.

[image]

It there anything I can do to get rid of that IE box? Or any other option to use to the same effect?

Thanks!

Maria

Comment: What kind of IE security box is caused by this?

Comment: What Pekka said ^^ - also, which version of IE? (usually under Help -> About)

Comment: IE8. This yellow irritating alert bar that comes on almost everything at the top of browser.

Comment: If I remove onfocus section it doesnt come on.

Comment: Are you running the page from your computer? (i.e. double clicked on the .html file?) Usually Internet Explorer does this for local files to prevent attacks. Open this and see if the yellow bar comes up. http://jsfiddle.net/25xBW/

Comment: Please quote what that alert bar is saying exactly.

Comment: @Peka he probably means this message http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/195/tn_19578/images/infobar.gif @Marko Ivanovski thanks too, I didn't know that.

Comment: Thank you so very much folks! Especially Marco! Damn it, it drove me crazy since 2 months. Fine, I can leave with it on my local computer but how am I to test while developing my files??? Irritating as hell! Problem solved, what matters is the site.

Comment: You're welcome! Use Firefox or Chrome! :)>

Comment: On a side note, I have all security settings at lowest, and I have everything enabled, nothing on PROMPT. Yet this irritating crap keeps coming on everything local.

Comment: Marko, I spent 3 hours reading the net and this forum trying to find a solution!!! How can I choose your answer as best or send you some points/credits? I really appreciate this.

Comment: I've copied it as an answer, hopefully it might help someone else in the future. I'm glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the page from your computer? (i.e. double clicked on the .html file?) Usually Internet Explorer does this for local files to prevent attacks. Open this and see if the yellow bar comes up. http://jsfiddle.net/25xBW